# Jasmine - testing promises. How to test function in callback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, jasmine

I have (Angular.js 1.5 + ng-redux) code:

```
update: function(itemId, value) {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    var params;
    params = {
      id: itemId,
      action: value
    };
    resultsAPI.change(params).then(function(results) {
      dispatch({
        type: "CHANGE_STETE",
        itemId: itemId,
        output: results
      });
    });
  };
}
```

or coffeescript:

```
update: (itemId, value) -> (dispatch, getState) ->
  params = {
    id: itemId,
    action: value
  }
resultsAPI.change(params).then(results) ->
  dispatch({
    type: "CHANGE_STATE"
    itemId: itemId
    output: results
  })
```

I want to write a test to see if request to API has been made ​​with correct parameters. 
I would also check if after .then() dispatch function is called. Any ideas on how to go about it?

Comment: In your test, you have to send the API request and then test it.  You can then use `toHaveBeenCalledWith()` functionality.  I'd recommend checking out this article: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/spy-on-javascript-methods-using-the-jasmine-testing-framework.html#fbid=ZMd4zHJBGuC

Comment: Google jasmine async test. There's tons of stuff. Please do research before posting to Stack overflow, if there's something the documentation you don't understand, include that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
it "call dispatch after .then", ->
  filterId = 1
  value  = "stop"

  params =
    id: filterId
    action: value

  dispatch = jasmine.createSpy("dispatch")
  dispatch = =>
      type: "CHANGE_STATE"
      filterId: 2

  spyOn(@resultsAPI, "change").and.callFake(-> dispatch())
  @ngRedux.dispatch(update())
  @InvestigationsResultsAPI.changeState(params)
  dispatch()
  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalled()
```